# How to write a D-Flip Flop in systemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I am currently in the process of designing a counter in SystemVerilog and I am unsure of how to design the D-flip flip module.

Comment: HW design should be based on one's own logic.. Moreover, doing a simple Google search might help. Refer to https://www.edaplayground.com/x/9 for asynchronous positive edge triggered D-ff.

Comment: No professional engineer would design a flip-flop module if they were designing a counter. They would design at a higher, more abstract level - so called _Register Transfer Level_ or _RTL_. Are you sure you want to be designing a flip-flop module?

Comment: I am trying to design a counter in systemverilog and using d flip flop chips. This is for am electrical engineering class.

Answer (score 0):

A flip-flop is inferred by synthesis tool for all signals assigned in an always_ff process.

So if you are designing an 8b counter, you would write:

```
logic [7:0] cnt;
always_ff @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin : proc_cnt
  if(!rst_n) cnt <= 0;
  else cnt <= cnt + 1;
end
```